# Uri with com.android.externalstorage.documents located on non primary volume

Tags: java, android, storage, android-contentprovider

I got a problem. I have `Uri` which reads something like:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/[volume_uuid]:[file_path]
```

I'm able to locate `StorageVolume` through `StorageManager.getStorageVolumes()`

If volume is primary: `StorageVolume.isPrimary()` - I understand that I can parse path as:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + file_path;
```

But how to locate path if volume is not primary? In the end I need to have plain `File` object referenced through it's absolute path.

P.S. For sure I do have all necessary permission: either static declared through manifest or runtime ones both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that I can parse path as

Not reliably. You are assuming a specific internal implementation of code that can vary by device manufacturer and OS version.

> In the end I need to have plain File object referenced through it's absolute path.

Step #1: Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the contents identified by the `Uri`

Step #2: Open a `FileOutputStream` onto some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)

Step #3: Copy the content from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`

Step #4: Use the resulting file, deleting it when it is no longer necessary

> For sure I do have all necessary permission

For sure you do not, as you have no permissions to access files on removable storage, outside of very specific locations (e.g., the second and subsequent paths returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`).

Comment: Ok, got it. Can I use for the same purposes `DocumentFile`?

Comment: @barmaley: `DocumentFile` does not do any of those steps on its own. Also, `DocumentFile` is only supposed to work for `Uri` values from the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), and I am uncertain where you got that `Uri` from. But, you are welcome to give it a try for things that you feel it will help with.

Comment: Exactly - in my case i'm dealing with uris returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

Comment: @barmaley: You are welcome to wrap those in a `DocumentFile`, then.